# Android Compression/Decompression Native Libraries

Tags: android, native, zlib, compression

Does Android have built in libraries for compression/decompression (besides zlib)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why doesn't zlib count?

Answer (score 0):

The java.util.zip package does the job (http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/package-summary.html)